# Java DateTimeFormatter parsing with special characters

Tags: java, datetime

I'm having some troubles getting my format right for using `DataTimeFormatter` to parse a date time `String` in the format of:

```
20200915095318.883[-4:EDT]
```

I have a `DateTimeFormatter` pattern that works to produce this format, but it doesn't work to parse the same String. That pattern is:

```
yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS'['x':'z']'
```

If there are other libraries for DateTime parsing that are more appropriate for this type of need I'll happily consider those as well. Right now my solution is a one off regex matcher for when I encounter this DateTime String and to manually build its parts. Which is gross.

Comment: What exception was thrown? Can you post the error message?

Comment: It would also be good to see a succinct set of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I think it's the format of the offset, supported ones (according to the [JavaDocs of `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) are `+0000; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15`, so an offset of `-4` isn't supported, it would require a leading zero. Now it's up to someone who can provide a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` that parses offsets without a leading zero. Might be possible, might be impossible, don't know yet...

Comment: In addition, I think (tried it myself) you don't have to escape the colon which separates the offset from the zone. Even not for formatting an instance of `ZonedDateTime`

Comment: `I have a DateTimeFormatter pattern that works to produce this format, but it doesn't work to parse the same String. That pattern is:

yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS'['x':'z']'` - This is not correct. This formatter will not produce an offset in a single digit (i.e. without a leading zero which is missing in your date-time string).

Comment: Why do people insist on creating new date time formats when ISO 8601 is beyond sufficient for everyone's needs? sigh...

Comment: It seems like one off code is required since the DateTimeFormatterBuilder is needed. I'll do that instead of a regex solution, but it's still a one off which stinks. I appreciate the help. Everyone confirmed the issue is folks getting creative rather than using industry standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only problem is that the `-4` in your string needs a leading zero, as @deHaar indicated in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64064664/java-datetimeformatter-parsing-with-special-characters#comment113288209_64064664), i.e.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS'['x':'z']'");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("20200915095318.883[-04:EDT]", formatter);
```

Answer (score 5):

java.time, the modern Java date and time API that I think you are already using, is indeed the best library for the job. This works since Java 9:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss")
            .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0, 9, true)
            .appendLiteral('[')
            .appendOffset("+Hmm", "+0")
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT)
            .appendLiteral(']')
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    String s = "20200915095318.883[-4:EDT]";
    
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(s, formatter);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(s, formatter);
    
    if (odt.getOffset().equals(zdt.getOffset())) {
        System.out.println(odt);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Something’s wrong here");
    }
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2020-09-15T09:53:18.883-04:00
> 2020-09-15T09:53:18.883-04:00[America/New_York]
> ```

Parsing into an `OffsetDateTime` uses the offset, `-4`, while parsing into a `ZonedDateTime` uses the time zone abbreviation, `EDT`. I check that the two agree about the offset because else I would not know which of them to believe. In your example string they do agree.

I am passing `+Hmm` as pattern to `appendOffset()`. Other choices include `+H`, `+H:mm`, `+Hmmss` and `+H:mm:ss`. Lower case `mm` and `ss` mean that minutes and seconds of the offset are optional. You should choose based on how an offset would look like if it is not a whole number of hours.

What do I mean by *since Java 9*? java.time, `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and its `appendOffset` method are all in Java 8, but only since Java 9 does that method accept a pattern with just one `H` for one-digit hour in it.

Comment: The date-time API was added in Java 8. Why do you write that your code _works since Java 9_ ?

Comment: @Abra [In Java 8 `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendOffset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) accepts only a limited number of patterns and none of the ones I have mentioned in the answer. They were all added in [the Java 9 version of the same method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). In Java 8 java.time *cannot* parse an offset in the `-4` format.

Comment: A well-researched and complete answer!