# Parse unknown DateTime string with Time Zone identifier

Tags: java, datetime, time

How can this string `20190612070000.000[-4:EDT]` be parsed into `ZonedDateTime`?

I've tried this pattern and bunch of others, but nothing works so far:

```
String dateString = "20190612070000.000[-4:EDT]";

ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss.S[x:z]"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no OOTB (Out-Of-The-Box) [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) with the pattern matching your date-time string. You can define one using [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .appendPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss.SSS")
                                .appendLiteral('[')                                
                                .appendOffset("+H", "")
                                .appendLiteral(':')
                                .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT)
                                .appendLiteral(']')
                                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
                                
        String strDateTime = "20190612070000.000[-4:EDT]";
        
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2019-06-12T07:00-04:00[America/New_York]
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Hi Arvind, What did you mean by `+H`, I got *Invalid zone offset pattern: +H* Java8

Comment: @YCF_L - `+H` is for zone offset hours. Please check this [online demo](https://ideone.com/6fpjxs).

Comment: I think this should work with Java9+ not with Java8 check this comment of [Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64064664/java-datetimeformatter-parsing-with-special-characters#comment113291241_64065884)